# Scala, SBT, Jenkins ?

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I have been a heavy user of jenkins for everything I need in a Java project build flow. Examples... Code Review, static code analysis like CheckStyle, findbugs etc through jenkins plugins as well as with Maven plugins. In addition, I have used Nexus for repository management and jenkins post build upload the artifact to the repository automatically and war files deployed to Tomcat after build.  Now, to get this much automated workflow with a web UI like jenkins, what is available for Scala? Is it still jenkins with appropriate plugins?  Can I completely go with SBT instead of maven if I continue to use jenkins?

Comment: [Looks like it](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Scala works well on either Jenkins or Travis CI, just using sbt.
Number of opensource projects, including the Scala compiler, Akka, and Cats are built using sbt.